# Master / detail view with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to build a master / detail view with data stored in Core Data. Which complicates things is that the shown values are not necessarily the raw values of the properties, but might need additional calculations.

### Core Data Entities

#### Transaction

- *amount* (always a positive value)
- *fromAccount*: source account for the money
- *toAccount*: destination account for the money

### Master view

The master view is a table view listing all the objects of the entity Transaction for a given Account (let's call it the represented account). This entails all transactions where the represented account is either the *fromAccount* or the *toAccount*.

The displayed data is:

- simple properties such as transaction *date* and *message*
- properties depending on the perspective: *amount* and *account*

  Transaction viewed from the perspective of the `fromAccount`:

  - amount: indicates a subtracted amount and is shown as `(amount * -1)`
  - account: show the `toAccount`

  Transaction viewed from the perspective of the `toAccount`:

  - amount: indicates an added amount and is shown as the positive value `amount`
  - account: show the `fromAccount`

The translation / interpretation of these dependent properties is done by the table view's data source. The view knows which Account it represents, so the data source can easily do the necessary calculations.

### Detail view

The detail view shows the values for a single Transaction selected in the master view.

The selected object in the table view is a descendant of NSManagedObject. Ideally I would bind the values of text fields /  popup menus to the properties of the Transaction. Due to the necessary interpretations this is impossible.

Right now I'm resorting to binding the values to methods such as `viewController.selectedObjectAmount` and `viewController.selectedObjectAccount`, which do the calculations. However, this seems like a lousy solution. Either I add a method for every property I want to use in my detail view, or I have a mix of methods in viewController and properties straight from the selected object itself.

My initial thought was using a "TransactionProxy" (descendant of NSProxy) which would have properties / methods for all the required properties I want to show. I gave this up as I couldn't get to work, but I'm still wondering whether it's an / the option.

Comment: just a variation of the millions "pass data/object/array to view controller" question. Who wants to select a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the detail view a property of type `Transaction` and populate the view with the data from that object. It's a very common pattern.

Comment: I don't think I understand it fully. If I do that, would I not still have to bind to Transaction.amount, keeping the issue?

Comment: What do you mean, "bind"? Just access or change `transaction.amount`. Just put `transaction.fromAccount.name` into a label. What is so confusing?

Comment: I'd like to bind my textfields etc in IB to my properties. The difficulty being exactly that I can't just bind to `amount`, but that I need a calculation to be done (use either amount or (amount * -1). The same goes for the accounts. I need to show either `fromAccount` or `toAccount`, which is easily solvable in my table, using its datasource, but I'm at a loss when it comes to a simple detail view with a bunch of fields.

Comment: You are confusing "properties" of controller classes that represent **UI elements** (such as a label) which you create in IB, with "attributes" of the managed object which represent the **data**.